# Calculate the number of days between selected date and current date using datetime-picker AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using [bootstrap datetime-picker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Fdatepicker) in angularjs

I disabled few days using the option dateDisabled of the date picker like this

```
        $scope.dateOptions = {
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
        minDate: new Date(),
        startingDay: 1,
        onChangeDate: countDays,
        dateDisabled: function (data) {
            var date = new Date(data.date)
            date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

            var date2 = new Date('2019-02-08')
            date2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

            return (date == date2.toString());
        }
    };
```

Now need to calculate the number of days between the selected date and the current date based on the date picker i.e. disabled date should not be count in the days calcluation.

[image]

If i selected the date as 10 feb 2019 then the number of days to be count as 
4 (using  current date - 5 feb 2019 ).

but it is coming as 5

The function get calls when i select the date from date picker

```
 function countDays(dateTime) {
     var fourDaysLater = new Date();

     fourDaysLater.setDate(dateTime.getDate() - 4);
    }
```

How to count dates which are enabled in the date picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question

> How to count dates which are enabled in the date picker?

You have disabled the dates using date picker but when you are counting the number of days between two dates you are using new date() which can't access your date picker's date.

You can do something like this -

```
function countDays(dateTime) {

     // Current date
     var currentDate = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

     // Selected date
     var selectedDate = new Date(dateTime).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

     // Count working days between selected date and current date
     while (currentDate < selectedDate) {

            if (currentDate != new Date('2019-02-08').setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {
                ++workingDays;
            }
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
    }

   alert(workingDays);  // Number of working days
```

Count the number of days between two days and exculde the